# chrome.mediaGalleries.getMetadata error handling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I can't handle the exception which happening within this method:

```
chrome.mediaGalleries.getMetadata(mediaFileBlob, { metadataType: "all" }, function(metadata){
console.log(metadata);
})
```

There is some files which cases an exception

```
Error in response to mediaGalleries.getMetadata: TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachedImagesBlobInfo' of undefined
```

There is no solution to handle this exception

NOTE: I have tried `try, catch, window.onerror, chrome.runtime.lastError`

Can anybody help me?

Seems they handle their exception by `console.error`and it become a impossible to handle this error again

ADDITION: This happening because `chrome api` do not have errorCallback's
Bellow shown code from `chrome.mediaGalleries` this is the case when `response` is `undefined` and code cannot reach to callback function
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a Chrome bug - API should not have unhandled exceptions _inside_ itself. You should file it at https://crbug.com/